# Api return 429 -possibilty raise threshold

Tags: routes, here-api, transit

I am using following api:

- https://transit.router.hereapi.com/v8/routes
- https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes

and while I use paralerization or async, I am recieving response

**429 - Too Many Requests**

I am using **Freemium** right now.

Is there any chance of increasing the number of calls before I hit the threshold?
Will be threshold raised if  **Pro** or **Enterprise** is payed?

Answer (score 0):

If you exceed the Location Services 250,000 Transactions or Data Hub 2.5GB Data transfer or 5GB Database storage included for free in the Freemium plan, you'll receive an email telling you to add payment details to your account. You'll have some "wiggle room" above your limits to help ensure your access is not unintentionally shut down. However, it's possible to exceed the threshold, including "wiggle room", which would result in account deactivation, even before we can notify you.

To keep your account active if you exceed the limits, add your payment details anytime on the Billing Management page, which you'll find under your username at the top right of the screen, provided you're signed in.

You'll receive an invoice for the extra usage as follows:

For Transactions, pay $1/1€ per 1,000 Transactions.

For Data transfer, pay $1/1€ per additional 100MB

For Database storage, pay $3/3€ per additional 5GB

Yes the threshold for the Pro plan is more as compared to the Freemium plan. For the Pro plan , it is 1 millon per month.Not only the threshold below are the key features for the Pro plan.

1>Transactions per month 1 Million

2>HERE Data Layers for 2 city map tiles with data refresh available

3>Data Hub Add-on

4>Live Sense SDK

5>Support via Customer Support Portal

You can upgrade your plan anytime on the Project Details page,which you'll find under your username at the top right of the screen, provided you're signed in. If you'd like to upgrade to a plan that’s not offered on developer.here.com, please contact us on  developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you.
Upgrades from Freemium to Add-On and Pro take effect immediately upon payment. Upgrade from Add-On to Pro takes effect at the end of the current billing period.